# Firebase CLI database:get request always return null

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am the owner of the firebase project from which I am trying to fetch the data, e.g.,  `firebase database:get /orders`. However, the request always returns `null`. I tried to set up different roles https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[myproject] with no luck. I have only one firebase project and it is selected as I can see in `firebase list`. I can deploy functions and app from the Firebase CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check that your `/orders` path exists in **Realtime Database** and not Firestore. The command `firebase database:get` is for interacting with Firebase Realtime Database only, not Firestore.